# What's the difference between [orden-de-palabras] and [sintaxis]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

What's the difference (if any) between [orden-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orden-de-palabras) and [sintaxis](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sintaxis)?  What I mean is, what are some examples (if they exist) that should have one or the other tag, but not the other?

Or, are they close enough that they could be synonyms?  I'm not sure about this because I've always been a bit vague about the term "syntax."

Comment: Viendo la descripción de "word-order" `Preguntas sobre el orden correcto de los componentes de una frase. Questions about the correct order of the components of a phrase.` diría que parecen sinónimos, pero entiendo que "word-order" es realmente una sub-etiqueta dentro de "sintaxis". Preguntas sobre epítetos (la _blanca_ nieve vs. la nieve _blanca_) o el orden de los adjetivos según algún criterio son sobre el orden de las palabras y no realmente sobre la validez de la sintaxis. Yo lo veo muy relacionado a "preferencia personal/regional" y cómo cambia el significado, no a validez de las reglas

Answer (score 1):

[sintaxis](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sintaxis) es un bloque grande que contiene distintos elementos, entre los que se incluye [orden-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orden-de-palabras) (y su sinónimo en inglés [word-order](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-order) —intentemos usar las etiquetas en castellano para estar hablando siempre de lo mismo).

A saber, la sintaxis trata de

Por ejemplo la pregunta [¿Es correcto “siempre quieren y terminan sometiendo”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2413/1674) trata sobre cómo construir una frase utilizando el sujeto elíptico. En ella, el orden de las palabras no es relevante, es decir, por mucho que le diéramos la vuelta, la frase "siempre quieren y terminan sometiendo” no cambiará la posible ambigüedad que menciona su autor. En tal caso, por tanto, corresponde utilizar [sintaxis](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sintaxis) pero no [orden-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orden-de-palabras).

Actualmente la definición de [sintaxis](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sintaxis) es [la siguiente](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/sintaxis/info):

> Acerca de cómo las palabras están organizadas y arregladas para formar frases y oraciones.
>   About how words are ordered and arranged to form phrases and sentences.

Y la de [orden-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orden-de-palabras) nos [dice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/orden-de-palabras/info):

> Preguntas sobre el orden correcto de los componentes de una frase.
>    Questions about the correct order of the components of a phrase.

Creo que la segunda es buena y adecuada. La primera creo que la podríamos mejorar utilizando la definición del DLE en [*sintaxis*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XzfiT9q):

> Parte de la gramática que estudia el modo en que se combinan las palabras y los grupos que estas forman para expresar significados, así como las relaciones que se establecen entre todas esas unidades.

Y decir algo así como:

> Preguntas sobre cómo combinar palabras para expresar significados.

Answer (score 0):

las palabras pueden cambiar de orden y a aveces al hacerlo las frases pueden adquirir diferentes significados, pero la sintaxis es lo que define las reglas de como se conforman los enunciados.

Osea:

las palabras pueden cambiar de orden dentro de un enunciado si se respeta la sintaxis. 
cuando las palabras cambian de orden el significado del enunciado puede cambiar. 
Si la sintaxis no se respeta el enunciado deja de tener sentido

ejemplo:

> "Me gusta lo que tengo" -- Enunciado original
>   "Tengo lo que me gusta" -- Diferente orden de palabras y diferente significado
>   "Gusta tengo que lo me" -- sintaxis rota, Enunciado pierde sentido.

la sintaxis es la segunda parte fundamental de los lenguajes y no se limita únicamente a gramática, las reglas sintácticas también son parte de lenguajes de programación y procesos numéricos.

es por esto mismo que la sintaxis es un tema importante en la traducción de textos debido a que en diferentes lenguajes la sintaxis es diferente.

en caso claro, la adjetivación en ingles y español

español :

> usual: "sustantivo" + 'Adjetivo"
>   inusual: "adjetivo" + "sustantivo"

ingles :

> usual: "Adjetivo" + "sustantivo"
>   NUNCA DE LOS NUNCAS: "Sustantivo" + "adjetivo"

Comment: O sea que traduciendo la respuesta a Meta: [orden-de-palabras] es un subconjunto de [sintaxis] para ti, ¿no?

Comment: exacto, y la sintaxis es un conjunto de reglas especifica para un orden de palabras para que algo pueda ser entendible.